# How to detect user movement status such as running walking transporting & resting etc

Tags: ios, core-location, move, status

I want to detect user movement status such as running walking transporting & resting etc.

I use corelocation to calculate the speed of user movement, but it is not so accurate. when  user stands still, the speed is not equal to 0.

Is there a sample or could somebody tell me how to implement this?